# Pointer vs. Reference in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In c++ this works with pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual void base_method() {
        cout << "this is the base\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void base_method() {
        cout << "this is the child\n";
    }
};

void test(Base & b) {
    b.base_method();
}

void test2(Base * b) {
    b->base_method();
}

int main() {
    Derived * d;
    Derived & d1();
    test2(d); //this works 
    test(d1); //this doesn't
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it that you cannot do the same thing with a reference like `Child & c()` passed into the test function. I ask this since pointers and references tend to behave similarly

Comment: What is "the same thing"?

Comment: @H2CO3 If you pass the reference to the test function it will not compile

Comment: @aaronman Euh, *why* do you expect it to compile? References are not pointers...

Comment: Do you pass the reference as `test(b)` or `test(*b)`? Hint try the 2nd one...

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but there are 2 test functions one takes a pointer the other a reference

Comment: @aaronman I don't get your question, what is "Why is it that you cannot do the same thing with a reference like Child & c() passed into the test function." if you want to pass by reference, you should call test(*b).

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer

Comment: `Child & c()` is a function declaration. you cant pass a function pointer to test. declare like so `Child c.` and call as so `test(c)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your example is poorly chosen. You shouldn't generally have naked `new`'s floating around user code.

The following example demonstrates the similarities:

```
 struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };
 struct Derived : Base { };

 void foo(Base *);

 void bar(Base &);

 int main()
 {
     Derived x;
     foo(&x);  // fine
     bar(x);   // fine and even better
 }
```

(Also note that a parent-child relationship is very different from a base-derived relationship. The latter is an "is-a" one, the former is a "supports-till-25" one.)

Comment: "supports-till-25"? It's worse that I thought.

Comment: I don't think this compiles

Comment: i'm not being dumb but what is parent-child relationship here?i'm only used to base-derived. sorry if this is dumb but i could not resist

Comment: btw I was posting this question to debate the parent-child base-derived semantic issue, i know I should have used derived instead

Comment: This does not compile and I'm not sure what a floating new is, you know my example compiles right?

Comment: @aaronman: How are you compiling KerrekSB's example? I just pasted it into stdin of g++ and it compiles fine without errors or warnings.

Comment: @Koushik: A lot of people, and unfortunately a lot of literature, uses the "parent-child" metaphor to describe, or at least name, classes in an inheritance hierarchy. I think the misguided notion is that a child (eventually) *inherits* its parents' riches... then again, that's only after the parents are dead, so I really don't know what they were thinking.

Comment: @aaronman: Your example might compile, but every aspect of it is in poor taste. Your code should basically never contain the word "new", except in very specific and very controlled circumstances. As you can see, dynamic object creation is entirely unnecessary for the purpose of demonstrating virtual dispatch (although virtual dispatch is generally only a good design decision for when the type is really not knowable at compile time...).

Comment: I don't have all my father's attributes and there are many situations in which I am not Liskov-substitutable for my father. Luckily.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: `struct Father {}; struct Son { Hand h; };` "I am the father" may cause slicing!

Answer (score 3):

```
Derived & d()
```

is a function declaration (return type Derived& and having no input parameter)and not object instantiation. This is C++'s MVP(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

use this syntax

```
Derived d;
```

and

call as so

```
test(d);
```

Comment: Not actually the *most* vexing parse, but vexing all the same.

Answer (score 3):

`Derived & d1();` does not do what you have assumed.

Have a look [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/empty-parens-in-object-decl.html):

[10.2] Is there any difference between List x; and List x();?
A big difference!

Suppose that List is the name of some class. Then function f() declares a local List object called x:

```
void f()
{
  List x;     // Local object named x (of class List)
  ...
}
```

But function g() declares a function called x() that returns a List:

```
void g()
{
  List x();   // Function named x (that returns a List)
  ...
}
```